# tcolorbox version 3 top alignment

Tags: vertical-alignment, tcolorbox

I write this simple latex file trying to make left and rigth tcolorboxes top aligned. Here's the code

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\pagestyle{empty}
%
\setlength{\topmargin}{0cm}
\setlength{\textheight}{23.5cm}
\setlength{\textwidth}{18.8cm}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{-1.1cm}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\begin{document}

\noindent\makebox[\linewidth]{\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}}

\fbox{
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.60\textwidth}
line 1\\
line 2\\
line 3\\
line 4\\
line 5
\end{minipage}
}
\hfill
\fbox{
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.30\textwidth}
line 1\\
line 2
\end{minipage}
}

\fbox{
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.60\textwidth}
\begin{tcolorbox}[title=\begin{center}gauche\end{center}]
line 1\\
line 2\\
line 3\\
line 4\\
line 5
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{minipage}
}
\hfill
\fbox{
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.30\textwidth}
\begin{tcolorbox}[title=\begin{center}droite\end{center}]
ligne 1\\
ligne 2
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{minipage}
}

\end{document}
```

The output from TeXLive 2016 using tcolorbox version 3 is bad
[image: bad ouput from version 3]

The output from same TeXlive 2016 but replacing tcolorbox directory
to version 2.80 give the expected result
[image: expected output here]

In your opinion, is it a bug introduce by tclorbox version 3 ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

With version 3.93, you can use `halign title` to avoid `\begin{center}...\end{center}`, `width=` to avoid `minipage` and `box align=top` to force top box alignment:

[image]

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\pagestyle{empty}
%
\setlength{\topmargin}{0cm}
\setlength{\textheight}{23.5cm}
\setlength{\textwidth}{18.8cm}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{-1.1cm}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\begin{document}

\noindent\makebox[\linewidth]{\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}}

\fbox{
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.60\textwidth}
line 1\\
line 2\\
line 3\\
line 4\\
line 5
\end{minipage}
}
\hfill
\fbox{
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.30\textwidth}
line 1\\
line 2
\end{minipage}
}

\fbox{
%\begin{minipage}[t]{0.60\textwidth}
\begin{tcolorbox}[width=.6\textwidth, halign title=center, title=gauche, box align=top]
line 1\\
line 2\\
line 3\\
line 4\\
line 5
\end{tcolorbox}
%\end{minipage}
}
\hfill
\fbox{
%\begin{minipage}[t]{0.30\textwidth}
\begin{tcolorbox}[width=.3\textwidth, halign title=center, title=droite, box align=top]
ligne 1\\
ligne 2
\end{tcolorbox}
%\end{minipage}
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works but the \fbox is not needed in my real work. I've added a before and after options to get it works without \fbox around                                                                              align=top, before=\par,after=\hfill     for the left box and            align=top, before=,after=\par                   for the rigth box

Answer (score 0):

Between version 3.40 and 3.50, the code for `before` and `after` changed to detect special situations. In your case, this changed a desired side-effect. But since `before` and `after` can be adapted, you can get the old behaviour by e.g. introducing an options like `mybeforeafter`:

```
\tcbset{
  mybeforeafter/.style={before={\par\smallskip\parindent=0pt},after={\par\smallskip}},% v 3.40
}
```

Adding this to your boxes gives the desired effect:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\pagestyle{empty}
%
\setlength{\topmargin}{0cm}
\setlength{\textheight}{23.5cm}
\setlength{\textwidth}{18.8cm}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{-1.1cm}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}


\tcbset{
  mybeforeafter/.style={before={\par\smallskip\parindent=0pt},after={\par\smallskip}},% v 3.40
}

\begin{document}

\noindent\makebox[\linewidth]{\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}}

\fbox{
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.60\textwidth}
line 1\\
line 2\\
line 3\\
line 4\\
line 5
\end{minipage}
}
\hfill
\fbox{
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.30\textwidth}
line 1\\
line 2
\end{minipage}
}

\fbox{
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.60\textwidth}
\begin{tcolorbox}[title=\begin{center}gauche\end{center},mybeforeafter]
line 1\\
line 2\\
line 3\\
line 4\\
line 5
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{minipage}
}
\hfill
\fbox{
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.30\textwidth}
\begin{tcolorbox}[title=\begin{center}droite\end{center},mybeforeafter]
ligne 1\\
ligne 2
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{minipage}
}

\end{document}
```